# What is the best way to send gps coordinates from onLocationChanged inside a service to UI?

Tags: android, service

I have created a service that implements LocationListener and uses the fused location provider. My problem is that I want to send the gps coordinates from onLocationChanged within the service to an activity that updates the UI. I have registered a BroadcastReceiver to send the data to the activity, but because the updates happen very frequenty (every second), the UI does not update all the time. Most of the coordinates never show up in the UI. My question is which is the best way to send the data from the onLocationChanged inside the service to the activity?

Here is my code:

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

LocationClient locationclient;
LocationRequest locationrequest;
private static final String TAG = "LocationService";
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION =  "com.example.fusedlocation.displayevent";
Intent intent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    int resp = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resp == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        locationclient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        locationclient.connect();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Service Error " + resp,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
            intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
}


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    if (locationclient != null && locationclient.isConnected()) {

        locationrequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationrequest.setInterval(2000)
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setSmallestDisplacement(0);

        locationclient.requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest, this);

    }

}
    @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (locationclient != null && locationclient.isConnected()) {

        locationrequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationrequest.setInterval(1000)
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setSmallestDisplacement(0);

        locationclient.requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest, this);

    }

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    locationclient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
    locationclient.disconnect();

}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    ....
    intent.putExtra("Latitude", location.getLatitude());
    intent.putExtra("Longitude", location.getLongitude());
    sendBroadcast(intent, null);
    ...
```

}

And my main activity is:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtConnectionStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConnectionStatus);

    txtLocationRequest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLocationRequest);
    timer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.timer);

    mAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
    mActivityIndicator = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.address_progress);

    mIntentService = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    mLocation = new Location("");
    intent= new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
}
...
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();       

    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);      
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        double latitude = extras.getDouble("Latitude");
        double longitude = extras.getDouble("Longitude");
txtLocationRequest.setText("Latitude: "+ extras.getDouble("Latitude")+"\n"+
        "Longitude: "+ extras.getDouble("Longitude")
        }
};
```

...
}

Comment: Post the code that you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some of this sort of thing and there are two things I can suggest that may help. one approach (which is what I do). is declare static variable for the things you want like currentLat and currentLong. then changes these on location change, then you can check these values in you main activity.

or you can use a handler, if you really need to know every time the location is updated

failing that you may be better off not using a service, as I understand it a service is still handled on the main ui thread so you aren’t making your app more efficient.

ok I see a bit better now

in you service, declare

```
something extends Service{

public static double curlat
public static double curlong
```

...the in

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    ....
    if(location.hasLatitude()){curLat=location.getLatitude();}
    if(location.hasLongitude()){curLong=location.getLongitude();}

    ..
```

then in your mainActivity

```
public void updateGui(){

 txtLocationRequest.setText("Latitude: "+ Service.curLat+"\n"+
    "Longitude: "+ Service.curLong);
    }
```

you may find this approach easier? then all you need to do is call update gui. What I also don’t understand is why is you current code not working?

Comment: I have uploaded part of my code. If not use a service what is a better way? The problem is that I want to send the data to more than one activities. So, how can I do that If I dont use a service?

Comment: The current code is working. The problem is that I added an integer to count the number of new locations inserted in the onLocationChanged method and I realized that the lat,long for example changed in the UI 2 times and the integer was 10, which means that 8 coordinates where never shown in the UI

Answer (score 0):

Try doing runOnUiThread() from your activity.